# '$ is undefined' error jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've got the following HTML and jQuery code, and whenever I try to load the page, Firebug gives me the 'ReferenceError: $ is undefined' error; as such, the jQuery code doesn't work. I'm using Coda 2.0.9 on Mavericks. I've loaded the jQuery library (using Google CDN) before the jQuery UI library, and both of those before the script I've written. In the Net section of Firebug, the only request that it shows is the font from Google Fonts. This is just a splash page so the code is minimal. For the life of me I can't figure this out so any help would be much appreciated.

```
<meta name="description" content="Description here" >
<title>This site is being updated</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika+Negative' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

```
        <h1 class="maintitle"> This site is getting cleared up! </h1>

        <img class="construction" src="images/construction_800.png">

        <div id='wrapper' style='text-align:center;width:auto; margin: 0px 90px'>    
            <div style='float:left;width:50%'> 
              <strong>Office 1</strong> <br>
              p. xxx.xxx.xxxx <br>
              f. xxx.xxx.xxxx
            </div>    
            <div style='float:right;width:50%'>   
                <strong>Office 2</strong> <br>
                p. xxx.xxx.xxxx <br>
                f. xxx.xxx.xxxx
            </div>
        </div>

        <p class="comeback"><strong>Please check back soon for the updated site</strong></p>

    </body>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".maintitle", ".construction", "div", ".comeback").fadeIn("slow");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're loading in Jquery Twice in the header.

Remove the last line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

The actual issue is that there is a conflict somewhere with the $ handler that jQuery uses.

If so, changing $ to jQuery like @Choineck should work.

Comment: Could also be his jQuery script

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case, and (as Tom said) it could be any script.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but that is my script (I renamed it). But I've tried every suggestion here and none of them have worked unfortunately. With Choinek's suggestion Firebug says both jQuery libraries load, but I'm still not seeing the effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".maintitle", ".construction", "div", ".comeback").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have a slight delay getting the jQuery from ajax.google
But you could also try something like

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Then

```
$j("...")
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid delays in getting the libraries other than storing them locally (eg. making the user load them directly from my site rather than use a cached copy from Google or MS that they already have)?

Comment: It's a known problem with ajax.google so switching CDN might work

Comment: Is there a particular source that's known for no (or less) delays? Because ideally I don't want the user to have to load them every time.

Comment: I tried that but the jQuery effects still don't happen. Any ideas?